# How do I find bugs that occur on different optimalization levels?

Tags: c, debugging, optimization, code-coverage

So I am using the C compiler and I have a case of a bug that happens on -O3, but not on any other optimization level. I am not going to give the joy of finding and fixing the bug away, but I am intrested: how do you go on a hunt for these kind of bugs? My default starting point is looking for variables that only get changed in interrupts, but that are not prefixed with `volatile` the compiler usually removes these.

But beyond that: I would not know. Any tips, or maybe even a structural method?

Comment: Get all the warnings from your compiler or lint. Understand them, and eliminate as many as possible.

Comment: compiling different .c files with at different -O levels may help you locate the bad file,.

Comment: Make sure you compile the code with as many warnings as possible enabled — and none of them firing.  If you're using GCC, use (at minimum) `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (probably with `-g` and either `-O2` or `-O3`, plus the relevant standard — e.g. `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`).  If the code does not compile squeaky clean under those options, fix the issues identified.

Comment: also, make sure your compiler version is up to date..."I am using the C compiler" - there is more than one...

Comment: if you know whuch file then use the optimize pragma to find which function https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.  it is possible you have found (or rediscovered) a bug in your compiler, in 25 years I have discovered 3 compiler bugs.

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger.  for most instances, that would be gdb, although there are several others.

Comment: Such "nondeterministic" bugs are often related to invalid memory accesses that have different effects due to different memory mappings. Unfortunately these are difficult to pinpoint, they can even disappear under debugger control. Try and find a variable that takes an abnormal value in the course of execution.